App is failing with 'taskLifecycleListener' bean initialization errors post Spring Boot 3.x upgrade
Spring Batch application is failing to start up with Spring Boot 3.0.16. Previously it was on Spring Boot 2.7.18(using Spring Boot managed Spring Batch version).
My application connects to MS SQL Server, H2 in local and using Hibernate framework.
It seems like Spring Boot has updated its managed Spring Batch version to 5.0.4 and involved some significant notes per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#ms-sqlserver. I tried looking into it but this didn't fix the errors.

Spring Batch application is failing to start up with Spring Boot 3.0.16. Previously it was on Spring Boot 2.7.18(using Spring Boot managed Spring Batch version).

My application connects to MS SQL Server, H2 in local and using Hibernate framework.

It seems like Spring Boot has updated its managed Spring Batch version to 5.0.4 and involved some significant notes per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#ms-sqlserver. I tried looking into it but this didn't fix the errors.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-25 17:20:56.433 [main ] [] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:291)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:260)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:205)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:981)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:79)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:131)
at org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.dao.JdbcTaskExecutionDao.getNextExecutionId(JdbcTaskExecutionDao.java:464)
at org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.dao.JdbcTaskExecutionDao.createTaskExecution(JdbcTaskExecutionDao.java:219)
at org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.support.SimpleTaskRepository.createTaskExecution(SimpleTaskRepository.java:115)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.cloud.task.repository.support.SimpleTaskRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createTaskExecution()
at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.doTaskStart(TaskLifecycleListener.java:293)
at org.springframework.cloud.task.listener.TaskLifecycleListener.start(TaskLifecycleListener.java:411)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288)
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Object 'TASK_SEQ' is not a sequence object.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:872)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:767)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3272)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:692)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:110)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:70)
... 34 common frames omitted



I tried this fro migration guide but this didn't help
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#ms-sqlserver.

With Spring Cloud Task 3.0, TASK_SEQ for SQL Server is no longer a table but a sequence.
In Spring Cloud Task 2.x, the DDL was
CREATE TABLE TASK_SEQ (ID BIGINT IDENTITY)

In Spring Clout Task 3.x, it is
CREATE SEQUENCE TASK_SEQ START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NO CACHE NO CYCLE;

You need to adjust your database schema accordingly. This is not covered in the Spring Batch migration notes as Spring Cloud Task is not in scope of Spring Batch, Spring Cloud Task is maintained separately.
You can see the change in the repository here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/commit/6dc83b8abe23820d9994d260a6f3225f3413a65b

My application is not managing sql scripts related to TABLE_SEQ
I believe TASK_SEQ table us created by Spring Cloud Task by default

Does your problem appear with an existing database that you with an upgraded application? Or does it appear when starting the app against an empty database?

If the problem appears against an empty database, then the problem is that the database initializer of Spring Cloud Task is not running.

When you put a break point in TaskRepositoryInitializer::afterPropertiesSet, does it trigger the initialization? Against H2 or against SQL Server?

Yup, it went through that code fine and I can see database connection is established fine. The issue specifically loading schema from Spring cloud task 3.x.x

Resolved this by renaming the existing TASK_SEQ table name and then created sequence TASK_SEQ with maxId+1 of task_seq table.
btw, Spring-cloud-task reference id/current_value of TASK_SEQ as a primaryKey in TASK_EXECUTION table. So, make sure you create a sequence with unique value otherwise you will end up with 'Primary Key violation exception on TASK_EXECUTION' table
Solution:

Execute below SQL/Liquibase script
-- Check if table exists and rename it
IF OBJECT_ID('TASK_SEQ', 'U') IS
NOT NULL
BEGIN
EXEC sp_rename 'TASK_SEQ', 'TASK_SEQ_OLD';
END
GO
DECLARE @LastValue BIGINT;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
-- Retrieve the last value from the task_seq table
SELECT @LastValue = ISNULL(MAX(id),0) FROM TASK_SEQ_OLD;
SET @SQL = N'CREATE SEQUENCE TASK_SEQ
START WITH ' + CAST(@LastValue + 1 AS NVARCHAR(20)) +'
MINVALUE ' + CAST(@LastValue + 1 AS NVARCHAR(20)) +'
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
NO CACHE
NO CYCLE';
--Execute the dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

Then Run Spring Batch application



As the TASK_SEQ SEQUENCE object found after above SQL execution, app starts using current_value from TASK_SEQ sequence and increment by 1 by default.

